# How to change stdin back to reading from terminal after using "freopen" (in C)?

Tags: c, stdin

I used ***freopen*** to redirect stdin to reading from a file, and it worked perfectly

```
FILE *fp = freopen(args[index + 1], "r", stdin);
        if(fp == NULL){
            printf("file not found\n");
            return 1;
        }
```

After that I do some processing and want to go back to reading from the terminal, but I can’t seem to figure out how to do that.

I'm closing the file using ***fclose***

```
fclose(fp);
```

I tried closing ***stdin*** too but it didn’t make a difference.

```
fclose(stdin);
```

I tried to

```
int savedStdIn = dup(0);
```

before ***freopen***, and

```
dup2(savedStdIn, 0);
```

at the end of the code (along with **fclose(fp)**) but that didn’t work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close:

```
// before reopen
int savedStdIn = dup(fileno(Stdin));
freopen(...) ;
...
// restore stdin
fclose(Stdin) ;
stdin = fdopen(savedStdIn, “r”)
...
```

In theory, close/dup approach can work, provided you flush the buffers. This is risky, and implementation dependent, as it attempt to bypass the studio library calls by accessing system calls.

```
// before reopen
int savedStdIn = dup(fileno(Stdin));
freopen(...) ;
...
// restore stdin
fflush(stdin):
Dup2(SavedstdIn), fileno(stdin))
```

Comment: stdin/stdout are not always reassignable.

Comment: @IlanSchemoul [Indeed](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note272):  "those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value returned by the fopen function may be assigned."  In other words, in general, **this answer will not work**.

Comment: Per opengroup.org: freopen man page:
The freopen() function is typically used to attach the preopened streams associated with stdin, stdout, and stderr to other files.

Also, from Apple Developers freopen: 
The primary use of the freopen() function is to change the file associated
with a standard text stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout).

In practice, this works with glibc and compatible run-time (musl, ...) - practically every Linux. So unless you are running in very "exotic" setup - freopen on stdin/stdout should be OK.

Comment: URL for the above:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/freopen.3.html
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/freopen.html