# Print in terminal after`freopen("file.txt", "wb", stdout);` (or similar solution to preserve a printing function)

Tags: c, file-io, stream, printf, stdout

I want to store the printed output of a function with `freopen("file.txt", "wb", stdout);` (or another solution, but the function `matrix_output_printf()` should remained untouched.
However, I want to be able to further print something after having closed `fclose(stdout);` as shown below but the `hello` of `printf("hello");` does not appear in terminal. Is it possible print hello in another way (on a MacOS system).

```
/* 
 *  main.c 
 *  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349098/stream-the-output-of-a-void-function-using-printf/75352112#75352112
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matrix_output();

void matrix_output_printf(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      printf("%d\t", i+j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main ()
{ 
  freopen("file.txt", "wb", stdout);
  matrix_output_printf();
  fclose(stdout);
  printf("hello");
  return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

The code provided in the answer is not working on my MacOS computer ( `'io.h' file not found`). Is there another solution portable for UNIX like systems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change stdin back to reading from terminal after using "freopen" (in C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005960/how-to-change-stdin-back-to-reading-from-terminal-after-using-freopen-in-c)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Fe2O3. Well not exactly as the question you are refering to deals with stdin and not stdout. Could maybe edit the code provided?

Comment: You can use the same technique with `stdout` as `stdin`.

Comment: Please do **NOT** close this as a dupe - the answer on the supposed dupe is [horribly wrong](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note272): "those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value returned by the fopen function may be assigned."

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AndrewHenle. It seems that you do not agree with the answer provided if i understand correctly. Would you have an alternative?

Comment: Why don't you pass `FILE*` to `matrix_output_printf` function, and use `fprintf` instead of `printf`? Then you only need to pass either `stdout` or file handle.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @user694733. Would it be possible to adapt the given code with your solution?

Comment: ~_Would it be possible to adapt the given code..._" This is contrary to your previous posting in which altering the code of the function was not possible... Is this a game?

Comment: @Fe203 it is not a game: the function matrix_output_printf should still remain unchanged as in your code but should also work for unix like systems

Comment: Okay... no "game"... but... You seem to not understand that the suggestion of @user694733 involves _changing_ the code of the untouchable function to use `fprintf()`... Perhaps you can edit this question to also point out that "a solution for MacOS is needed."

Comment: And I used the `fprintf` solution in a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348998/write-the-output-of-a-function-having-many-printf-statement-in-a-text-file/75350326#75350326.

Answer (score 1):

Tried and tested on my Windows box:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>

void matrix_output_printf() {
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            printf( "%d\t", i+j );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    int saved = _dup( fileno( stdout ) );

    freopen( "file.txt", "w", stdout );
    matrix_output_printf();
    fclose( stdout );

    _dup2( saved, 1 );

    printf( "hello\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fclose( stdout );`?  I doubt that will be portable.  Replacing the underlying file descriptor for a closed `FILE *` [is almost certainly undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.1p2): "Whether or not the call succeeds, the stream is disassociated from the file and any buffer set by the setbuf or setvbuf function is disassociated from the stream (and deallocated if it was automatically allocated)."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Appreciated... Thank you. While there may be a proper portable solution, this was offered as a "works for me" Windows specific answer. While I understand the ideals set for SO answers, sometimes 'sufficient' may be sufficient, imho `:-)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Fe203. But indeed @AndrewHenle seems to be right: the code is not working on my MacOS computer (` 'io.h' file not found`). Do you have another solution portable for UNIX like systems?

Comment: @ecjb Not one that I could test because I don't have a MacOS development environment or machine. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

If `stdout` was originally tied to the console, you can reopen the stream to `/dev/tty`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matrix_output_printf(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", i + j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() { 
    freopen("file.txt", "w", stdout);
    matrix_output_printf();
    freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

This should work on most unix systems, such as macOS, but if `stdout` was redirected to another file or device, reopening it with `freopen` won't work.  You could try and duplicate the system handle with `dup()` and use `fdopen()` to open a standard stream after closing `stdout`, but there is no guarantee that the stream returned by `fdopen` will be the same as `stdout`.

Using `freopen` for your purpose is a hack. A much better approach is to rewrite `matrix_output_printf` to take a `FILE *` argument for the output stream, or a `const char *filename` for the name of the file to produce:

```
void matrix_output_printf(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp = stdout;
    if (filename) {
        fp = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            /* handle error */
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\t", i + j);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    if (filename)
        fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

1. Flush the stream
2. Duplicate `stdout`'s file descriptor before calling the function, duplicate a file descriptor open to the desired file to the stream's original file descriptor value
3. Call the function
4. Restore the original `stdout` descriptor

Similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void matrix_output_printf(void){
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      printf("%d\t", i+j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main()
{ 
  int fd = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
  int savedStdoutFD = dup(fileno(stdout));
  fflush(stdout);
  dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(fd);

  matrix_output_printf();

  fflush(stdout);
  dup2(savedStdoutFD, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(savedStdoutFD);

  printf("hello\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this code is inherently unsafe to use in a multithreaded process.

@chqrlie had the best answer: "A much better approach is to rewrite `matrix_output_printf` to take a `FILE *` argument for the output stream, or a `const char *filename` for the name of the file to produce".